# Django admin login doesn't work without default backend

Tags: django, django-admin, backend

My users are using Shibboleth for authentication, so I'm using RemoteUserBackend as my AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS tuple. This is working fine for any url, except the admin.
When I try to login I get a message telling me my password is wrong.
Why is that and what can I do to fix it? I'd probably use differents backends, one for my project and the other one for my admin interface, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I am currently trying to setup shibboleth with django any chance you can point me towards good example? or can you share an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Django admin site only allows access for users with the `is_staff` flag set to True.

As a one off, you can set the `is_staff` flag for a particular user through the shell:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User.objects.get(username="fernando")
>>> u.is_staff = True
>>> u.save()
```

After making the above change, your user should be able to access the admin site.

For new users in future, you may want to subclass the `RemoteUserBackend` and override the [`configure_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/#django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend.configure_user) method to set the `is_staff` flag where appropriate.

Comment: I was already staff in the database. Also, I tried to override the configure_user like this:   def configure_user(self,user): user.is_staff = True user.save(),but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked that the `REMOTE_USER` header is being set properly? Have you added some print statements to make sure that `request.user` is the user you think it is? There's nothing special about using the admin app with different backends. if you can't see the admin pages, then I'm pretty sure that you are not logged in with an active user with `is_staff=True`.